# Scrapy selector working in shell, but not in the spider itself

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm relatively new to python and scrapy; just started learning from tutorials a few days ago.

Like the title says, I've been trying to get a simple text scraping operation done as practice, by scraping chapters from fanfiction.net. However, I've run into a roadblock where even though my test selectors in the shell work perfectly fine, the spider itself still returns nothing when I run the command `scrapy crawl fanfiction -o fanfiction.json`.

Here is the code that I have so far; it's essentially a modified version of the tutorial code from doc.scrapy.org.

```
import scrapy
class FFSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fanfiction"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12580108/1/Insane-Gudako',
        'https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12580108/2/Insane-Gudako',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
        inspect_response(response, self)
        for chapter in response.css('div.fanfiction'):
            yield {
                'summary': chapter.css('.storytext p').xpath('text()').extract()
            }
```

In the inline shell call, testing using `chapter.css('.storytext p').xpath('text()').extract()` returns the text properly, but once the spider finishes crawling, fanfiction.json is still an empty file.

What is the problem here?

Comment: how do you write the results ?

Comment: Load the page with javascript disabled and `div.fanfiction` is no where to be seen. When scraping with scrapy, always disable javascript script by going to `about:config` and then setting `javascript.enabled` to false

Comment: Found the problem. Thanks Tarun! I shouldn't have kept the div thing from the tutorial.

Comment: where-ever you open any page in scrapy shell use `view(response)` it will show what exactly page that scrapy is seeing and you will have better judgement why you are not getting any value at that `xpath`

Comment: Welcome to SO: you may want to read [ask] and [mcve].